# docker-composeでApacheを起動しようとするとコンテナは起動するが、Apache起動しない

Tags: docker, apache, windows-10, docker-compose

## 環境

- windows10 home
- Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a（Docker toolbox）
- docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b

## やろうとしていること

CentOS8のイメージにApacheをインストールし、起動させたいです。
なお、Apacheが入ってるイメージは意図的に利用していなく、
本番とCentOSのバージョンなどを合わせるためにやっております。
（本番はコンテナが使えないので、環境だけでも合わせようとDockerを使っています）

## やったこと

下記のDockerfileを作成しました。

```
FROM centos:8

# CentOSを最新に
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum upgrade -y

# タイムゾーンをJSTに
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime

# 言語を日本語に
RUN echo "LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8" | tee /etc/sysconfig/i18n

# Apacheを入れる
RUN yum install -y httpd
RUN apachectl -v
RUN systemctl enable httpd


CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

これをdocker-compose.ymlから呼び出します。

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  apache:
    build: './data/apache'
    volumes:
      - ./data/apache/log:/var/log/apache/
      - ./data/apache/conf:/etc/apache2/conf
      - ./data/apache/conf.d:/etc/apache2/conf.d
    ports:
      - 10080:80
```

ビルドを行い、起動します

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

ビルド後、プロセスが立ち上がったかの確認

```
$ docker-compose ps                                                                                                     指定されたパスが見つかりません。
     Name          Command     State           Ports
------------------------------------------------------------
apache_1   /sbin/init   Up      0.0.0.0:10080->80/tcp
```

何故か「指定されたパスが見つかりません。」と表示されますが…とりあえず起動してそう。

- 0.0.0.0:10080
- localhost:10080
- 127.0.0.1:10080

などにアクセスしましたがつながらりませんでした。

---

dockerのイメージにアクセスしてみました。

```
docker-compose exec apache bash
```

そこでapacheの状態を見てみようとコマンドを叩くとエラーが出ました。

```
# apachectl status
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

---

調べてみると以下のようなものが見つかったので試していきます。

---

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

> `sudo service redis-server start`を使え

とのことなので、使ってみます。

```
service start apache
bash: service: command not found
```

そもそもserviceコマンドがない…

---

[docker for windowsのdockerデーモンを共用する | WSLでdockerのインストールからdocker-composeまで動かす - Qiita](https://qiita.com/tettsu__/items/85c96850d187e4386c24#docker-for-windows%E3%81%AEdocker%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%85%B1%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

docker for windowsを使っていない……

---

などです。
他にも見ましたが、似たようなことばかりでした。

この原因、当たりがつく方がいらっしゃいましたら、解決方法などお知恵をお貸しいただきますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: CentOS8では `service` コマンドの代わりに `systemctl` コマンドを使います (Dockerfileの中でも使用していますよね)。/ その他に気になるのは、標準以外のポートを使用しているので、ファイアウォールの設定を確認してみるなど、でしょうか。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます！　
> CentOS8では service コマンドの代わりに systemctl コマンドを使います　
そうですよね…ググって出てきたので念の為やってみました。　
しかし、動かなかったので `apachectl` や `systemctl start httpd` 等してみましたがだめでした…